# How to conditionally replace a value with a value from the same row in a different column using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data frame:

```
ID   X    Y    Z
1    3    5    3
2    1    4    1
3    5    3    5
4    0    7    7
```

I want column Z to equal column X, unless column X is equal to 0. In that case, I would want column Z to equal column Y. Is there a way to do this without a for loop using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Z'] = np.where(df['X'].eq(0), df['Y'], df['X'])
```

Or [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['Z'] = df['Y'].where(df['X'].eq(0), df['X'])
```

Output:

```
ID   X    Y    Z
1    3    5    3
2    1    4    1
3    5    3    5
4    0    7    7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `np.where()`:

```
df['Z'] = np.where(df['X'] == 0,df['Y'],df['X'])
```

Basically this translates to "If X = 0 then use the corresponding value for column Y, else (different than 0) use column X"